# Как запустить программу в Visual Studio 2010? имеются файлы .c, .h

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Я никогда не программировал в Visual Studio, но тут понадобилось найти один проект и запустить посмотреть, что да как, я нашел его, но вот как запустить не могу понять, прикрепил скриншот с имеющимися файлами, подскажите как запустить, чтобы можно было посмотреть на саму уже работающую программу? Спасибо.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можно создать пустой проект и добавить к нему нужные файлы, затем кнопка `Run`

Comment: Сделал, теперь что-то запускается, появляется командная строка, проходят расчеты (как и должно быть), но сразу же оно через секунду закрывается и я не успеваю ничего посмотреть и понять, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: окно закроется как только оно не нужно. Либо настраивайте отладчик, либо добавьте в конец фиктивный ввод или system("pause"); либо же просто с консоли запустить.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gVSNTkS5ru0

Comment: А еще есть такая вещь -  `nmake`. И не надо создавать никакие проекты, если, конечно, `makefile` под VC++ дело писан...